# JavaScript Reflection to Find Where a Function Is Defined

Tags: javascript, reflection

I'm working on a large JavaScript project where a lot of external scripts are included. How can I find where a function is defined without having to resort to searching every file on the server?

PHP, for example, has a class named "ReflectionFunction" which is able to return information about a function:

$function_name = 'array_orderby';
$function_info = new ReflectionFunction( $function_name );
echo "The $function_name function is located in: " . $function_info->getFileName() . ' on line: ' . $function_info->getStartLine() . '.';

### Sample Output

The array_orderby function is located in: /var/www/mysite.com/inc/script.php on line: 49.

Is there something like that in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in JavaScript, because any function may be overridden at any point, even at runtime.

Comment: A hacky option (depending on your use case) would be to try to deliberately get your target function to throw an error and then check the console...